# Tried to Install Wordpress on Subdomain, Broke Main Domain Links

Tags: wordpress, installation, subdomain, file-not-found, addon-domain

I have a main portfolio site hosted through MacHighway. My hosting package allows me to have two domains. I thought I'd register a new domain to experiment with some new things. So I bought a new domain, went into my main site's cPanel, registered it as an Addon Domain, and tried to install Wordpress on it. I got Wordpress working on it just fine, but then all of the links on my main site broke. So I deleted the files for the new site to see if that would help, but all of the links on my main site are still broken. The pages all say 'file not found.' Where did I go wrong? How can I fix this? I don't care about the new site at the moment. I just need to get my main site back the way it was. Help?

[This is my site](http://mcography.com).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I visited Settings > Permalinks and everything works again.